# Ebay API (convertedCurrentPrice) php

Tags: php, currency, ebay-api

the following code behind the value of a product on Ebay dollar:

```
echo $i['sellingStatus'][0]['currentPrice'][0]['__value__'];
```

I'm trying to convert the currency Real (Brazil) as follows, but is not working:

```
echo $i['sellingStatus'][0]['convertedCurrentPrice'][0]['BRL']['__value__'];
```

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

The part of the XML that mentions the value is:

```
<sellingStatus><currentPrice currencyId="USD">21.84</currentPrice><convertedCurrentPrice currencyId="USD">21.84</convertedCurrentPrice><sellingState>Active</sellingState><timeLeft>P2DT4H30M45S</timeLeft></sellingStatus>
```

Answer (score 0):

eBay won't do raw currency conversions for you, but it'll do courtesy conversions when you retrieve items from one eBay locale to another. eBay doesn't have a presence in Brazil, so you can't request pricing information in BRL.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the price in a specific currency, you need to make the call with the SiteID that corresponds to that country. For example, if you want the price in Sterling Pounds, you would make the call with the SiteID 3, for UK. If you would make the call with the SiteID 77, for Germany, you would get the price in EUR. But, unfortunately,  there is no SiteID for Brazil. 
You can see a list of all eBay sites with their specific SiteIDs [here](http://www.ebay.com/gds/ALL-EBAY-WORLD-SITES-/10000000204201621/g.html)